# addClass doesnt work, cant define (this)

Tags: jquery, this, addclass

here is my javascript:

```
$(function() {
$(".image2").click(function() {var image = $(this).attr("rel");
$('#image2').hide();
$('#image2').fadeIn('slow');
$('#image2').html('<embed height="253" width="440" wmode="transparent" src="' + image + '"></embed>');
return false;
 });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#thumb2 a").each(function() {
 var image = $('#image2 embed').attr('src');alert(image);
 if(this.attr('rel') = image ) 
 $(this).addClass("open");
 });
});
```

and my html:

```
<style>
 #thumb2 img { border:1px solid #dfdfdf; padding:3px; height:29px; margin-top:5px; opacity:0.3; }
#thumb2 img:hover { border:1px solid #fc7200; opacity:1.0; }
 .image2.open { border:1px solid #fc7200; opacity:1.0; }
</style>

<div id="image2"><embed height="253" width="440" wmode="transparent" src="images/kameralar.swf"></embed></div>
<div id="thumb2">
<a href="#" rel="images/kameralar.swf" class="image2" ><img src="images/t1.png" border="0"/></a>
<a href="#" rel="images/standalone.swf" class="image2"><img src="images/t2.png" border="0"/></a>
<a href="#" rel="images/mobil.swf" class="image2"><img src="images/t3.png" border="0"/></a>
<a href="#" rel="images/3b2.swf" class="image2"><img src="images/t4.png" border="0"/></a>
<a href="#" rel="images/canon.swf" class="image2"><img src="images/t5.png" border="0"/></a>
<a href="#" rel="images/indigovision.swf" class="image2"><img src="images/t6.png" border="0"/></a>
</div>
```

can't add class to a link whose rel attribute is the same with embed src attribute... jquery is added... pls smb help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `.attr()` isn't a method available on the DOM element and `=` sets (or attempts to) the left side, rather than comparing both.  To fix the first, you need to wrap it, so this:

```
if(this.attr('rel') = image )
```

needs to be:

```
if($(this).attr('rel') == image)
```

Also note the double `==` for a comparison, rather than a set.

---

However, a better solution that both shorter and more efficient would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var image = $('#image2 embed').attr('src');
  $("#thumb2 a[rel='" + image + "']").addClass("open");
});
```

Comment: @venom, then you may want to consider up-voting and/or accepting the answer =)

Comment: Nick Craver, 4 minutes left ) but there is a problem... do you know how to add the class to a image rather then to a link a?

Comment: @venom - yeah sure, just do `$("#thumb2 a[rel='" + image + "'] img").addClass("open");`

Comment: @Nick Craver, thx again! but ) this is being static, i mean, when i push the link to change the embed file, the selected (open) img doesn't change... i think it must be done by click in a previous script?!

Comment: @venom -you want to remove `open` from another `<img>`?

Comment: @Nick Craver, yes ) but i want it to be as the selected item, while changing files, like a slider, i mean just one seleced img..

Comment: @venom - So t is working, but you want it to change when you click another?

Comment: @venom - In that case you'll need to `.removeClass()` on the others, for example, run `$("#thumb2 a img").removeClass("open");` just before the `.addClass()` line.

Comment: @Nick Craver, Thank you very much! For solving all my stupid questions )) im just newbie sorry! )

Comment: @Nick Craver, pls have a look at this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410041/want-the-thumbnail-changed-class-with-the-same-timing-as-random-embed-object-chan